# Difference between @ModelAttribute and org.springframework.ui.ModelMap.get()?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm trying to use an Object as the command object of a `<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>`element.

In the controller's GET method, I add the Object like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String renderForm(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    [...]
    model.addAttribute("voting", voting);
    [...]
}
```

The rendered form does show the command object correctly when defined like this:

```
<form:form action="vote" method="PUT" commandName="voting" name="oform">
```

Now when trying to access the form's command object back in the controller, on the POST method, I have two approaches. First, I declare the @ModelAttribute in the signature:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String newVoting(@ModelAttribute("voting") Voting voting, HttpServletRequest request) { [...]}
```

Or I access the ModelMap and get the value from the underlying map:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String newVoting(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Voting voting = (Voting) model.get("voting");
    [...]
}
```

When doing the first, I get the object as it was submitted by the form. Doing the latter, I get the object as it was BEFORE being handled by the form.

Why does the form's submit not change the object in the ModelMap and why does the @ModelAttribute differ from whats in the actual model? I feel like the name 'ModelAttribute' should result in the same object like getting the object directly from the model.

Maybe @ModelAttribute is kind of misleading?

***EDIT***
Forgot to mention that the object is a @SessionAttributes

```
 @SessionAttributes({"voting", "state"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach, using the @ModelAttribute annotation does **two** things:

1. **Creating** the Voting object using the submitted form data;
2. **Exposing** the Voting object to the view by adding it to the model (request, or, in your case, session because of the @SessionAttributes({"voting"})).

Your second approach uses just the ModelMap, so it's getting only model attributes (from the request or, in your case, the session, depending on the @SessionAttributes annotation). This approach does **not** use the data from the submitted form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that it does _not_ use the data from the form - but why? Or why does the @ModelAttribute not use the same model which I can access through ModelMap?

Comment: It does not use the data from the form because you do not "tell" Spring to do that.